# How do I disable ADF Rich Faces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, oracle-adf

I want to use my own javascript and not the ADF client side code. How do I disable the rich faces pieces in ADF? Is there a setting in web.xml I can use? Any help would be appreciated. I just don't particularly like the javascript that gets downloaded to my pages. I want to use AngularJS and jQuery but they occasionally conflict with the ADF Client pieces so I would like to turn those off. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot happen, since ADF components itself uses ADF Client Side APIs, either you use something other than ADF Rich Faces or try to workout your Javascript with ADF Client Side APIs.